# Improve jQuery autocomplete part of textield

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jquery-autocomplete

I have a text area where the autocomplete kicks in after the user types an @ sign. Similar to the way Twitter handles user name autocompletion. I use the jQuery [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and [caret](https://github.com/DrPheltRight/jquery-caret) plugins.

Normally autocomplete replaces the entire text field with whatever the user selects. In this case it only replaces the part after @. It even works if there are multiple @ signs in the text.

My CoffeeScript is a bit rusty, so I was wondering if anyone can suggest some improvements. In particular I don't like the way I pass variables like the current cursor position between the search and source method.

```
$('.myTextArea').autocomplete
search: (event,ui) ->
  # Figure out where in the text we are currently typing
  # Cursor position:
  target = $("#" + event.target.id)  # I'm sure there's a more elegant solution
  window.cursor_pos = target.caret()
  window.word = getWordAt(event.target.value, window.cursor_pos); 

  if window.word[0] == "@"
    $('#spinner').show()
  else
    return false
open: (event, ui) ->
  $('#spinner').hide()
focus: (event, ui) ->
  return false
source: (request, response)  ->
  $.getJSON("/users/autocomplete_username", { term: window.word.slice(1) }, response);
select: (event,ui) ->
  start_of_word =  window.cursor_pos - window.word.length + 1
  start = event.target.value.substring(0, start_of_word)
  ending = event.target.value.substring(window.cursor_pos, event.target.value.length)

  event.target.value = start +  ui.item.id + ending
  target = $("#" + event.target.id) 
  target.caret(start_of_word + ui.item.id.length )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good instinct re: passing cursor position between search and source—attaching things to `window` leads to death!! :) Locally scoped vars will work fine and will be safer (see below).

Another thing I noticed at a glance was your use of `word[0]`, which is undefined in some browsers; for string char access, you're actually supposed to use [`charAt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp) which is cross-browser friendly. I made the change here in addition to the var scoping:

```
cursor_pos = word = null

$('.myTextArea').autocomplete
  search: (event,ui) ->
    # Figure out where in the text we are currently typing
    # Cursor position:
    target = $("#" + event.target.id)  # I'm sure there's a more elegant solution
    cursor_pos = target.caret()
    word = getWordAt(event.target.value, cursor_pos); 

    if word.charAt(0) == "@"
      $('#spinner').show()
    else
      return false
  open: (event, ui) ->
    $('#spinner').hide()
  focus: (event, ui) ->
    return false
  source: (request, response)  ->
    $.getJSON("/users/autocomplete_username", { term: word.slice(1) }, response);
  select: (event,ui) ->
    start_of_word =  cursor_pos - word.length + 1
    start = event.target.value.substring(0, start_of_word)
    ending = event.target.value.substring(cursor_pos, event.target.value.length)

    event.target.value = start +  ui.item.id + ending
    target = $("#" + event.target.id) 
    target.caret(start_of_word + ui.item.id.length )
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this out soon.